# Automate the creation of Partial Classes from an entity data model

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

If I create an entity data model using the using the model first approach and building my model from an existing database is there a way that I could then automate the creation of partial classes to then allow me to extend the model to fit my requirements.  So for example were I to model the Northwind Database then, amongst others, entities would be created for 'Customer' and 'Order'.  I would like to find a way to then have visual studio to build a set of partial classes for each of the entities and put them into separate files.

I have no idea if this is doable in the first place, or if it is what the best way to go about doing it would be.  To that end I would welcome any suggestions and / or good basic examples of where to start learning how do to this sort of thing.  Ideally any such examples would have content in vb as well as c#.

Many thanks

Comment: If you build your model from a database you work database first (not model first). Did you try adding a code generation item to your edmx and inspect the t4 template (the tt file)? This would, by the way, also allow you to work database first with the preferred DbContext API.

Comment: Gert you are of course correct I should have said 'Database first' not 'Model First'.  On your second point whilst I appreciate that that the DBContext api is the preferred way to go I do have sound reasons for not doing so in this case.

Comment: @DomSinclair may I ask what that reason is? DbContext is a wrapper around ObjectContext. If necessary, you can cast a DbContext to an ObjectContext but with normal scenarios you can use the simpler API that the DbContext exposes.

Comment: Of course you can.  I'm use ComponentOne's Studio for Entity Framework and LiveLinq a great deal.  As of yet they do not seamlessly work with the simpler api exposed by the db context.  That's not to say that they won't, just that they don't yet.

Comment: @DomSinclair You can also add a code generation item for ObjectContext and try to edit the t4 template (I must admit I'm not a star at it, but I had some success previously by copy & paste).